# Как использовать react hooks + redux thunk?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

Кто использовал redux-thunk + hook useDispatch?

```
// reducer
export const makeApi = (apiKey) => () => {
  const api = new Api(apiKey)
  return {
    type: SET_PROP,
    payload: { field: 'API', value: api },
  }
}

// component
const dispatch = useDispatch()
// code ...
useEffect(() => {
  dispatch(makeApi(apiKey))
  // так вызов не работает, но если изменить на 
  dispatch(makeApi(apiKey)()) // то все ок
}, [])
```

Со стороны js все ясно, но я ожидаю увидеть тут работу redux-tunk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать примерно так:

```
import React from "react";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import SubComponent from "./SubComponent";

const initialState = {
  items: [],
};

export const fetchItems = () => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    dispatch(loadingAction());
    const asyncData = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        if (Math.random() > 0.3) {
          resolve(["abc", "def", "ghi"]);
        } else {
          reject(["error happend"]);
        }
      }, 1000);
    });
    dispatch(successAction(asyncData));
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch(errorAction(error));
  }
};

const loadingAction = () => ({ type: "LOADING" });
const successAction = (data) => ({ type: "SUCCESS", payload: data });
const errorAction = (error) => ({ type: "ERROR", payload: error });

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "LOADING":
      return { ...state, items: ["loading..."] };
    case "SUCCESS":
      return { ...state, items: action.payload };
    case "ERROR":
      return { ...state, items: action.payload };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const store = createStore(reducer, applyMiddleware(thunk));

const Redux = () => {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <h1>Redux</h1>
      <SubComponent />
    </Provider>
  );
};

export default Redux;
```

SubComponent.js:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { fetchItems } from "./Redux";

const SubComponent = () => {
  const items = useSelector((state) => state.items);

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchItems());
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h3>SubComponent</h3>
      {items.map((item) => (
        <div key={item}>{item}</div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default SubComponent;
```

вот в этом коде:

```
export const makeApi = (apiKey) => () => {
  const api = new Api(apiKey)
  return {
    type: SET_PROP,
    payload: { field: 'API', value: api },
  }
}
```

должна быть прописана асинхронная логика:

```
export const fetchApi = (apiKey) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
   // установить состояние загрузки (dispatch loading action)
   // получить данные с сервера
   // dispatch success action
  } catch {
   //  если произошла ошибка dispatch error action
  }

}
```